# How to properly require any Ruby gem in an Apache CGI application?

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems, cgi, require

My Ruby CGI scripts doesn't work when I require any gem. I would like to use the "peach" gem in my app, and it was installed by "gem install peach", however I installed it as root. My test app, called "gemtest":

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "cgi"
require "peach"

cgi=CGI.new(:accept_charset => "UTF-8")

puts "Content type: text/plain; charset: 'UTF-8'"
puts
puts "It Works!"
```

It always trows an error in the apache error log:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
cannot load such file -- peach
(
LoadError
)
\tfrom /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
\tfrom /opt/lampp/cgi-bin/gemtest:6:in `<main>'
End of script output before headers: gemtest
```

I also tried to set up LOAD_PATH amd GEM_PATH environment variables in my Apache's httpd.conf file with directive "SetEnv", and I always restarted the Apache daemon:

```
SetEnv LOAD_PATH "/home/my_username/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/"
SetEnv GEM_PATH "/home/my_username/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/"
```

But I had no success. How to require properly any gem when running simple CGI apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the user who is trying to load the gem, most probably doesn't have access to the gem installed for your username

Check the username that loads the apache service in your apache configuration, most probably its the nobody user, and install the gem for that user

```
sudo su - nobody
gem install peach
```

If you don't want to deal with different gems for different users, you can always use bundler

Comment: My config file shows user "daemon" and group "daemon":
<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>

Comment: so in the commands I gave you, instead of doing
`sudo su - nobody` do `sudo su - daemon` and install the gem for the daemon user and try again, btw, when you are logged in as the daemon user, do: `irb` and then within irb do: `require "peach"` to make sure that the `daemon` user can load the gem without problems, and please let me know if your cgi is working after the suggested update

Comment: I also had to define a password for user "daemon" woth "passwd daemon" and modify /etc/passwd to add a default shell for user "daemon" /bin/bash instead of /bin/false. Then I was able to login as user "daemon". I also made a directory "daemon" in /home and changed it owner and group to "daemon" with chmod and chgrp respectively. Then I was able to install the gem with "gem intsall peach". I also was able to run IRB as user "daemon" and successfully require the installed peach gem. However my CGI script still doesn't work, and I got the very same error lines in my Apache log "error.log".

Comment: after you are done testing remove the environment for /bin/bash and put it back to /bin/false. It was not necesary to add a password for the daemon user, since the password asked with sudo is the password for the root user. Did you remove the LOAD_PATH and GEM_PATH after these updates? otherwise it will still try to look for the files on the other user directory.

Comment: I tried both, either removing those two directives or point them to the "/home/daemon/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems" directory. Same result.

Comment: Problem solved, I had to use this directive in httpd.conf:
SetEnv GEM_HOME "/home/daemon/.gem/ruby/2.2.0"

Shorter path, ending with only the version number, instead of suffix "/gems" and environment variable GEM_HOME instead of LOAD_PATH and GEM_PATH. I took the idea from here https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4405282